# Multiple statements in a ranged for loop

Tags: c++

I'd like to know if it's possible to convert this expression

```
vector<Mesh>::iterator vIter;
for(int count = 0, vIter = meshList.begin(); vIter < meshList.end(); vIter++, count++)
{
...
}
```

into something along the lines of C++ 11

I'd like to get something like this:

```
for(auto count = 0, auto mesh : meshList; ; count++)
{ 
... 
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Nope. Range iteration is what it is. You must initialize `count` separately, use range iteration, and manually increment `count` at the *beginning* of the loop (initializing `count` to one less than its starting value).

Comment: The first expression is not legal `C++`. You can't put two different types in a comma separated initializer. `vIter` in the `for` scope is an `int`.

Comment: @Galik For some reason I always forget that the types have to be the same. It just seems like such a logical feature (to be able to init multiple types) that it's hard to imagine why it's not implemented like that. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The best you can do is the following:

```
int count = 0;
for(auto &mesh : meshList)
{
    ...
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness's sake alone, I just want to point out that you *can* define those two in the for loop's init-list (if your really want to) by (cheating and) aggregating them:

```
for(struct { int count; decltype(meshList)::iterator vIter; } _{0, meshList.begin()} ;
    _.vIter < meshList.end(); _.vIter++, _.count++)
{
  // ...
}
```

<kbd>[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59bd585b43dacbbd)</kbd>

But as you may have noticed it's verbose, ugly, and totally not worth it. The solution in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53799815/817643) is better by a factor of 100 at least.

Comment: I think this is a bad answer